# ChangeLog Plugin Maven - configuration in POM

Tags: maven, changelog

I want to configure the changelog plugin in my pom.xml...

but there is a reportSets section, so I wonder where I have to put the plugin?

Maybe into the configuration part of the scm plugin (reportPlugins, ...)

Answer (score 3):

The plugin goes in the reporting section of your pom.xml.

The example in their documentation shows how to configure the reportSets:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changelog-plugin/examples/selecting-reports.html

Unlike build plugins which are configured under `<build>`, reporting plugins are nested inside a `<reporting>` element directly under your root `<project>` element like so:

```
<project>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <!-- one or more reporting plugins go here -->
    </plugins>
  <reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: okay. but I thought that the reporting section is deprecated?

Comment: I got it... I have to nest it inside the <configuration> of the maven site plugin!!!

Answer (score 1):

a bit more particularised:

`
            
                org.apache.maven.plugins
                maven-site-plugin
                3.3

```
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-changelog-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.2</version>
                            <reportSets>
                                <reportSet>
                                    <id> file-report </id>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <type> range </type>
                                        <range> 30</range>   
                                    </configuration>
                                    <reports>
                                        <report>file-activity</report>
                                    </reports>
                                </reportSet>
                            </reportSets>
                        </plugin>
```

And then... it should work!